# Importing .CSV grouping and finding quartiles/IQR

Tags: r

I would like to use R to find quartiles 50, 75 and 90% and the interquartile range.

My .csv file has 78 columns and about 100k rows. I was using excel initially and grouping by SKU and Vendor and doing an array of the cost in descending order. I will need to run this on a larger file so I need to learn how to use a more robust tool.

I would like to group by the SKU Number and the Vendor Name. I would like the quartiles to be based on the "Cost" field. I am not sure how to accomplish this so that I only see cost broken out by SKU and Vendor name. The data will look something like below.

```
SKU Vendor COST
173 A   2.66
194 B   121.22
201 B   86.07
241 B   81.51
243 B   78.09
534 C   16.32
534 D   1.72
534 D   1.721428571
534 D   1.722
534 D   1.722166667
534 D   1.7225
534 D   1.723333333
534 D   2.0237
802 D   0.1355
802 D   0.135666667
802 D   0.19
802 D   22.8
```

Comment: Here's a helpful link for intro to group summaries in R: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-summaries-with-summarise

Comment: `aggregate(df$Cost, list(df$SKU), quantile, 0.5)` - `aggregate(df$Cost, list(df$SKU), quantile, 0.75)` - `aggregate(df$Cost, list(df$SKU), IQR)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using dplyr

first, use `group_by`, then use `summarize` and set the `quantile`s that you want to use. subset by [] to pull out the quantile you want. `quantile(cost, probs(.5, .75, .9)[1]` will give you the .5 quantile for example.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(sku = c(176, 176, 176, 534, 534, 534, 534, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3),
                 Vendor = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
                 cost = c(23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 45, 65, 22, 33, 44, 5, 88, 55))

df_summary <- df %>%
    group_by(sku, Vendor) %>%
    summarize(q50 = quantile(cost, probs = c(.5, .75, .9))[1],
              q75 = quantile(cost, probs = c(.5, .75, .9))[2],
              q90 = quantile(cost, probs = c(.5, .75, .9))[3])


> df_summary
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   sku [?]
    sku Vendor   q50   q75   q90
  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    3. C       55.0  71.5  81.4
2    4. B       33.0  49.0  58.6
3    4. C       44.0  44.0  44.0
4  176. A       34.0  39.5  42.8
5  534. A       61.5  64.2  65.9
6  534. B       61.5  69.8  74.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular old base functions.
Notice that both me and Matt interpreted "group by the SKU Number and the Vendor Name" quite literally. I also massaged the example data to make it a little neater.

```
tt <- structure(list(SKU = c(194L, 194L, 194L, 241L, 241L, 241L,
534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 802L, 802L, 802L,
802L), Vendor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("B", "D"), class =
"factor"), COST = c(2.66, 121.22, 86.07, 81.51, 78.09, 78.2,
1.72, 1.721, 1.722, 1.7221, 1.7225, 1.7233, 2.0237, 0.1355,
0.1357, 0.19, 22.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-17L))

summ <- function(x) {
    c(quantile(x, probs=c(0.5, 0.75, 0.9)), IQR=IQR(x))
}

aggregate(COST ~ SKU + Vendor, tt, summ)

#   SKU Vendor  COST.50%  COST.75%  COST.90%  COST.IQR
# 1 194      B  86.07000 103.64500 114.19000  59.28000
# 2 241      B  78.20000  79.85500  80.84800   1.71000
# 3 534      D   1.72210   1.72290   1.84346   0.00140
# 4 802      D   0.16285   5.84250  16.01700   5.70685
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. When inputting your exact code, it works. However, if I want it to read the values in each column without defining them as you did above, how can I do that? As I mentioned there will be millions of rows with different values. Right now, I imported the .csv into the console and have been researching how to write those columns to a data frame. The next step will be to execute the structuring like you and Matt suggested however I would like it to group unique vendors and unique manufacturers then calculate the quartiles/IQR at that level. Thoughts?

Comment: @mkelmhle: Multiple columns like COST that you want to summarize, or multiple columns like SKU and Value that you want to group by? Please edit your example data to reflect this character.